# Folders from the original theme missing in the _site build

Tags: jekyll, jekyll-theme

To use the [Agency Jekyll Theme](https://github.com/y7kim/agency-jekyll-theme) I initially created the site with `jekyll new`, then edited the `Gemfile` and `_config.yml` to reflect that I'm using the agency theme.

I can see that the theme is installed correctly

```
$ bundle info agency-jekyll-theme
  * agency-jekyll-theme (1.0.0)
        Summary: Agency Jekyll Theme is a jekyll theme gem, based on Agency theme created by Start Bootstrap.
        Homepage: http://github.com/laklau/agency-jekyll-theme
        Path: /home/hbucher/.gem/gems/agency-jekyll-theme-1.0.0
```

However when I try to build the site, several pieces go missing as

```
$ bundle exec jekyll serve -P 4100
Configuration file: /home/hbucher/git/tests/jekyll/_config.yml
            Source: /home/hbucher/git/tests/jekyll
       Destination: /home/hbucher/git/tests/jekyll/_site
 Incremental build: disabled. Enable with --incremental
      Generating... 
       Jekyll Feed: Generating feed for posts
     Build Warning: Layout 'post' requested in _posts/2023-08-02-welcome-to-jekyll.markdown does not exist.
     Build Warning: Layout 'page' requested in about.markdown does not exist.
     Build Warning: Layout 'style' requested in style.css does not exist.
                    done in 0.255 seconds.
 Auto-regeneration: enabled for '/home/hbucher/git/tests/jekyll'
    Server address: http://127.0.0.1:4100//
  Server running... press ctrl-c to stop.
[2023-08-02 01:15:34] ERROR `/vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js' not found.
[2023-08-02 01:15:34] ERROR `/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js' not found.
[2023-08-02 01:15:34] ERROR `/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css' not found.
[2023-08-02 01:15:34] ERROR `/vendor/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css' not found.
[2023-08-02 01:15:34] ERROR `/vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js' not found.
[2023-08-02 01:15:37] ERROR `/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css' not found.
```

When I look at the theme folder, all these files are there, they are just not copied to the _site location.

Am I goofing on the way I am building the site and making the theme dependency?

Thank you.